# How can I send output of a Filebeat in one system to a File in another system?

Tags: filebeat

Generally filebeat can send output to a file in a local system but I want to send output to a file in remote system.
can any one tell me whether it is possible or not?

Answer (score 0):

If the remote system is windows, you can create a remote shared folder.